# brand new to programming - declare a variable?

Tags: javascript

Totally new to Javascript and programming in general.  I'm trying to work through a tutorial and cannot get past step 1!  This is what it is asking and does not give any other instructions:

1)Declare a variable called name.

2)Assign the variable name the String value of your name.

3) Use the console.log function to print "Hello name", where name is your name.

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

I've tried:

```
var name = "my name"
var = "name"
```

Where do I enter the console.log part?  In the same .js file as the above entry or does it go in a separate file?  How do I run it?
I've tried several Google searches to try to figure this out but haven't been able to piece together an answer.

Comment: I think you should try working through a different tutorial. The one you're using assumes you know more than you do.

Answer (score 2):

Do this in the same js file :

```
var name = ""; /* Declare variable */
name = "my name"  /* Assign the variable name the String value of your name */
console.log("Hello " + name); /* Use the console.log function to print "Hello name", where name is your name. */
```

- Put it in the same js file.
- Call the js file in a html file.
- Run html file in web browser Open console of the web browser and you
  should see the message.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean "call the js file in a html file"?

Comment: Like @charles-clayton said, you could probably refer to another tutorial. 

To answer your question, save your javascript to myscripts.js.  Create index.html and add the below.  Then open index.html in internet browser
`
<html>
  <head>
 <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
 

  </body>

</html>
`

Answer (score 1):

> 1)Declare a variable called name.

```
var name = "test";
```

> 2)Assign the variable name the String value of your name.

```
var name = "Aja Lee";
```

> 3) Use the console.log function to print "Hello name", where name is your name.

```
var name = "Aja Lee";
console.log("Hello " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it goes in the same .js file. It is javascript that will output the text provided to the console. If you are using IE, you can see the console by opening the developer tools (F12) and going to the console tab. Other browsers will have a similar feature.